# HTPC and MAME box setup advice

Tags: linux, htpc

I'm planning my HTPC / MAME box combo PC for the lounge. I know what hardware I need, I'm looking for software and setup advice, and if you have done this before I'd appreciate your input!

I want this *nix based, a customized Debian or Ubuntu, other distros would do as well. I'm open to ideas. There will be no processing bottlenecks so I'm happy to sacrifice a 'light' setup for maintainability and easy of use.

**HTPC:** Video and music player - *XBMC / Moovida / ?*

**MAME:** NES, Sega emulators, WINE layer and native games - *emulation side is sorted*

I'd like to control the whole box with an IR remote, the keyboard I only want to pull out for system maintenance, if rarely. [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org) would be my choice, I have never used it or setup a IR remote before though. Can I use it to emulate keyboard input, so I can navigate and do a select few commands?

This box won't be online so streaming is not on my list of requirements. I'd also like to manage files/media on any USB storage devices connected to the box.

Any insight how I can control this box with just the IR remote? Switching between the HTPC and MAME interfaces with it, and managing media?

Thanks again to any replies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because MAME is prerelease software https://meta.superuser.com/q/13276/11116

Comment: **Note to close voters:** I found no evidence that this is pre-release software. It has had numerous official major releases; in fact there was another stable release in July of this year, and  Google ported MAME to Native Client 6 yrs ago, allowing MAME to run inside Chrome.  The close vote appears to be a case of trolling the site over a disagreement referenced in the linked Meta discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good experience with MythTV (under Mythbuntu).

Comment: MythTV is a PVR, since my box won't be online a PVR would be useless to me. Thanks though.

Comment: It does more than just act as a PVR. It has a framework to launch emulators. http://www.mythtv.org/docs/mythtv-HOWTO-16.html I built a MAME arcade machine and am running MythTV to pick the games.

Comment: How did I only see this comment now? Thanks :)